# Determining when WebBrowser Control Started processing the HTML 

Tags: browser, webbrowser-control, mshtml, iwebbrowser2

Is there a way to determine when the webbrowser control starts processing the HTML of the URL it navigated to? Looking for any event raised other than onreadystatechange (which does not have clear state for this)? Ontitlechange is not accurate enough for all use cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to settle on title change. Not exactly what I wanted, but the closest.